# iOS 13 beta WebKit breaks support for cookies

Tags: cordova, webkit, wkwebview, ios13

I've got a working Cordova based app, currently with relatively large user base. No problem so far except [this one](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12074) which Apple won't fix. It's OK though, we created ugly workarounds just to keep moving...

But, here comes iOS 13 (beta 8) and we learn that WebKit in this release doesn't send cookies back to server **at all**. Not once, not on the start - never. The release of iOS 13 is few weeks ahead and I simply don't know what are we to do when all users upgrade to it and our app stops working...

We use cookies for session management, nothing fancy, classical old Jetty based back end. The workaround I did for the first-time-use problem is to append jsessionid parameter to URL on each request and then strip that on server side, convert to cookie and send further down the chain. I don't know if it is safe to use it all the time assuming that WebKit stops sending back cookies. Here are some related bugs pending but it's unlikely Apple will even look at them:

- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=200857
- https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/121415

Anybody experiencing similar problems? How do you deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was acknowledged and fixed by the [WebKit team](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=200857) and gets released in iOS 13.2. I tested the beta version and it seems to work now.

Comment: Do you have any knowledge on when we can expect iOS 13.2 to be released to the public? I couldn't find any useful information about that. What I'm asking is it worth using that plugin or can I just wait a bit?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my ionic 3 app.
I found workarounds using :

- https://github.com/sneas/ionic-native-http-connection-backend
- https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/#installation

By replacing the API calls from rxjs with the native objective C http call, the cookie persist well from the http response of the backend.
Maybe, you can try with this ...

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. Unfortunately we are not with Ionic but plain Cordova, ended up sending session id as part of URL and adjusting session management on server side. The incredible thing is that nobody in Apple WebKit seems to care. How it even possible to do major release with degraded performance which breaks things is beyond me..

Answer (score 1):

Add this plugin https://github.com/oracle/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr, it intercept XHR requests and handle them by this plugin.
It works for me.

Comment: Our app is based on Axios http client, it's a mature app, I don't see how it's possible to replace all the requests to go through this workaround plugin.. Thank you all the same!

Comment: @Dima Just add this plugin, nothing more, and you'll see magic. If you are using http, not https, you have to add `<preference name="InterceptRemoteRequests" value="all" />` to config.xml

Comment: @DoctorWho  - Thank you! Yes, it seems to have fixed our problems completely. Magically. I don't quite understand what this plugin actually does.. It appears to be a savior for the situation. But I am not entirely sure if it's a good idea to fix bugs with plugins. Hopefully anyone from WebKit project or Apple can chime in and clarify the situation..